# JavaScript - How do I extract string in If/Else statement

Tags: javascript, string, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to use the If/Else statement to write certain text on the screen after searching through the imgNumber variable. For some reason, it only writes the string 'cockroaches' no matter which text is contained in the imgNumber variable.

Also, the imgNumber is a random string (it will always be one of the strings in the myImages variable).

What am I missing here?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeImg(imgNumber) {
var myImages = ["images/homepage/homepage-header.jpg", "images/homepage/homepage-header-3.jpg", "images/homepage/homepage-header-5.jpg"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';

var imgNumber = myImages[newImgNumber];

if (imgNumber = "images/homepage/homepage-header-5.jpg")
  {
  document.write('cockroaches');
  }
else if (imgNumber = "images/homepage/homepage-header-3.jpg")
  {
  document.write('ants');
  }
else
  {
  document.write('termites');
  } 

var n=myImages.indexOf("images/homepage/homepage-header-5.jpg");
document.write(n);

}
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` conditions are wrong, you need to compare using 2 equals signs. So: `==` not `=`
What you're doing in there is assigning the value of the strings to your `imgNumber` variable...

You can find more info about this on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Nah, it's a common minor oversight and I'm sure it has happened to all of us at least once...

Answer (score 0):

Using `=` is assigning the value. To compare values, you need `==`

Answer (score 0):

1) Like answered before, use ==
2) In future, use more correct variant:

```
var imgNumber = Number("a4r t 4r43 43a b345b 123 cc gaeg4".replace(/\D+/g,""));
switch (imgNumber) {
 case 0:
  // code here
 break;
 case 1:
  // code here
 break;
 default:
  // code here
 break;
}
```